# Retrieve the LANGID for French (Canada) on Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, registry, windows-mobile-6, soti

I'm writing a script using [SOTI](http://www.soti.net/) Package Manager and I'm trying to find the particular key I can use to retrieve what the current Windows Mobile Regional Setting is for Language.

If it's French (Canada) I want to display post-install script messages in French, otherwise I want them in English.

I've got the ability to check a registry value while running the post-install script by using the following syntax (for example):

```
set myVar=REG://HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Windows CE Tools?VN=Platform
```

I've looked at the MSDN articles on using [SetLocaleInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa913806.aspx) and [MAKELANGID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202928.aspx). I've gotta be honest in that I'm not sure how I'd go about figuring out what the French (Canada) LANGID actually is.

Anyone off the top of their head be able to tell me where I need to be checking for it or better yet, how you figured that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following value: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\nls\DefaultLCID`

The DWORD value will be the [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) of the currently active regional settings.
So for `French (Canada)` it would be 0x0c0c, and for `English (Canada)` it is 0x1009.